# using Microsoft.XMLDOM post IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xpath

It seems that Microsoft is moving away from using ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") beginning with IE 10.  I have a very conplex web based system that makes extensive use of XPath.  I thought rather than re engineer the system I would just put in a meta tag that would get IE to use an IE8 compatibility mode.  So with this tag at the top of the page in question

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

The IE browser does seem to enter IE8 mode.  My problem is that everything works fine when using Visual Studio on my dev. machine but strangely when the browser accesses my production server instance I get:

Automation server can't create object (for ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")).

The question is why would the browser behave differently depending on what server it is hitting when it is executing the same code?

Thanks as always to the community!

Comment: Is the production server sending some real HTTP header `X-UA-Compatible` which might override the meta in your code?

Comment: I checked the Response Header and I don't see anything.  Also checked the page source and I set the meta tag setting the emulation.  All looks the same as on the dev server.

Comment: Is there a public URL we could check?